# How to calculate inventory per day for each product given days are missing in between in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm stuck on one of the requirements, I am looking to calculate inventory quantity per day for each product in PostgreSQL. We have data like this:

```
goodsmovementid productid   quantity    warehouseid updatedon
1,409   1,052   720 2   7/01/2019 16:33
1,409   1,052   -55 2   7/23/2019 16:33
1,412   1,052   -10 2   7/25/2019 16:33
1,415   1,052   -35 2   7/28/2019 16:33
1,416   1,052   -83 2   8/2/2019 16:33
1,419   1,052   -24 2   8/5/2019 16:33
1,409   1,102   300 3   8/22/2019 16:33
1,410   1,102   -25 3   8/23/2019 16:33
1,412   1,102   -10 3   8/23/2019 16:33
1,415   1,102   -35 3   8/27/2019 16:33
1,416   1,102   -83 3   8/28/2019 16:33
1,419   1,102   -24 3   8/30/2019 16:33
```

I need to convert this to:

```
productid   quantity    updatedon
1,052   720 7/1/2019
1,052   720 7/2/2019
1,052   720 7/3/2019
1,052   720 7/4/2019
1,052   720 7/5/2019
1,052   720 7/6/2019
1,052   720 7/7/2019
1,052   720 7/8/2019
1,052   720 7/9/2019
1,052   720 7/10/2019
1,052   720 7/11/2019
1,052   720 7/12/2019
1,052   720 7/13/2019
1,052   720 7/14/2019
1,052   720 7/15/2019
1,052   720 7/16/2019
1,052   720 7/17/2019
1,052   720 7/18/2019
1,052   720 7/19/2019
1,052   720 7/20/2019
1,052   720 7/21/2019
1,052   720 7/22/2019
1,052   665 7/23/2019
1,052   665 7/24/2019
1,052   655 7/25/2019
1,052   655 7/26/2019
1,052   655 7/27/2019
1,052   620 7/28/2019
1,052   620 7/29/2019
1,052   620 7/30/2019
1,052   620 7/31/2019
1,052   620 8/1/2019
1,052   537 8/2/2019
1,052   537 8/3/2019
1,052   537 8/4/2019
1,052   513 8/5/2019
1,102   300 8/22/2019
1,102   265 8/23/2019
1,102   265 8/24/2019
1,102   265 8/25/2019
1,102   265 8/26/2019
1,102   230 8/27/2019
1,102   147 8/28/2019
1,102   123 8/29/2019
1,102   123 8/30/2019
1,102   123 8/31/2019
1,102   123 9/1/2019
1,102   123 9/2/2019
```

And the list goes on till today's date.

Key points:

- product can start its first transaction from any date so the result set shall show data from start date till today's date, one row for each day  for each product  starting from first transaction's date.
- we can have multiple transactions per day per product

Comment: Thanks mark for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate the dates.  Then, you can aggregate the original data by day and use `lead()` so you can fill in the intermediate dates:

```
select t.productid, gs.dte,
       sum(t.quantity) filter (where gs.dte = t.dte) over (partition by t.productid order by gs.dte) as amount
from (select productid, updatedon::date as dte, sum(quantity) as quantity,
             lead(updatedon::date) over (partition by productid order by updatedon::date) as next_date
      from t
      group by 1, 2
     ) t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.dte, coalesce(t.next_date - interval '1 day', current_date), interval '1 day') gs(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0fdd523e279ce8710b71a9df1a0f2dca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks gordon, I tried that , but the quantity sum is not getting populated correctly, so for a product the quantity sum is just getting added to itself in the next missing days , you can refer to the problem in this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/JLi9smb.png , original data is : https://pasteboard.co/JLi6Aqz.png

Comment: @TalhaIftikhar . . . I fixed the answer.  It had a logical error ("wishful programming" as I think of it) which is fixed with the `filter` clause.  It also had what I consider a syntax error  -- `lead()` with no `order by` -- and I'm surprised Postgres doesn't complain about that.

Comment: Thanks a zillion gordon for solving and teaching me some thing. exactly what I was looking for.